# Mapping JSON into Class Objects

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I am trying to map my JSON file into a class object, and then update the cards based on the newly received JSON.

My JSON structure is like this

```
 {
        "$class": "FirstCard",
        "id": "1",
        "description": "I am card number one",
        "Role": "attack",
        "score": 0,
        "tag": [
            "string"
        ],................}
```

my Class looks like this:

```
  class CardInfo {
  //Constructor
  String id;
  String description;
  String role;
  int score;

}
```

How can I map the values in my JSON file into the fields of objects created from CardInfo class?

**Update**

the following trial prints null at **ci.description**, does this mean the object was never created ?

```
const jsonCodec = const JsonCodec
_loadData() async {
  var url = 'myJsonURL';
  var httpClient  = createHttpClient();
  var response =await httpClient.get(url);
  print ("response" + response.body);
  Map cardInfo = jsonCodec.decode(response.body);
  var ci = new CardInfo.fromJson(cardInfo);
  print (ci.description); //prints null
}
```

**Update2**

Printing cardInfo gives the following:

> {$class: FirstCard, id: 1, description: I am card number one,........}

Note that it resembles the original JSON but without the double quotes on string values.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
class CardInfo {
  //Constructor
  String id;
  String description;
  String role;
  int score;

  CardInfo.fromJson(Map json) {
    id = json['id'];
    description = json['description'];
    role = json['Role'];
    score = json['score'];
  }
}

var ci = new CardInfo.fromJson(myJson);
```

You can use source generation tools like <strike>https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen</strike> https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable to generate the serialization and deserialization code for you.

If you prefer using immutable classes https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value is a good bet.

Comment: Please check the updated section in my post, I try to print one field in the object ci, and all I get is null.

Comment: What does `print(cardInfo);` print?

Comment: It is working now, I had a minor typo mistake in the key that maps to JSON value, thank you very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your JSON from a url do as follows:

```
import 'dart:convert';

_toObject() async {
  var url = 'YourJSONurl';
  var httpClient  = createHttpClient();
  var response =await httpClient.get(url);
  Map cardInfo = JSON.decode(response.body);
  var ci = new CardInfo.fromJson(cardInfo);
}
```

Please refer to the main answer if you want to know how to setup your class so that your JSON fields can be mapped to it. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I created some useful library for this using reflection called `json_parser` which is available at `pub`.

https://github.com/gi097/json_parser

You can add the following to your `dependencies.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  json_parser: 0.1.1
  build_runner: 0.8.3
```

Then the json can be parsed using:

```
DataClass instance = JsonParser.parseJson<DataClass>(json);
```

Follow the `README.md` for more instructions.

Comment: Is it working with dart 2.0? The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.1.0.flutter-ccb16f7282.

Comment: If you are using the latest version, then yes! :)

Comment: Error : depends on json_parser >=0.0.2 <0.1.4 which requires SDK version >=1.19.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.

Comment: Use `json_parser: ^0.1.6`

Comment: same error : Because json_parser >=0.1.4 depends on build_runner ^0.10.1+1 and App depends on build_runner 0.8.3, json_parser >=0.1.4 is forbidden.
So, because App depends on json_parser ^0.1.6, version solving failed.

Comment: Make sure you use `build_runner: ^0.10.1+1`. Please read the `README.md` in the repo.

Comment: Good, enjoy. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found is [this medium post](https://medium.com/@boylenssen/converting-the-response-from-chopper-to-an-object-642fd46608ff)

Which converts the Json to dart very easily

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'post_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class PostModel {
  int userId;
  int id;
  String title;
  String body;
  PostModel(this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.body);
  factory PostModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PostModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PostModelToJson(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate them if you don't want to create them manually.

Add dependecies to `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  json_annotation: ^4.0.0
dev_dependencies:
  build_it: ^0.2.5
  json_serializable: ^4.0.2
```

Create configurtion file `my_classes.yaml`:

```yaml
---
format:
  name: build_it
  generator:
    name: build_it:json
---

checkNullSafety: true

classes:
- name: CardInfo
  fields:
  - { name: id, type: String? }
  - { name: description, type: String? }
  - { name: role, type: String?, jsonKey: { name: Role } }
  - { name: score, type: int? }
  - { name: tag, type: List<String>, jsonKey: { defaultValue: [] } }
```

Run build process:

```
dart run build_runner build
```

Generated code `my_classes.g.dart`:

```dart
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'my_classes.g.g.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// build_it: build_it:json
// **************************************************************************

@JsonSerializable()
class CardInfo {
  CardInfo(
      {this.id, this.description, this.role, this.score, required this.tag});

  /// Creates an instance of 'CardInfo' from a JSON representation
  factory CardInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CardInfoFromJson(json);

  String? id;

  String? description;

  @JsonKey(name: 'Role')
  String? role;

  int? score;

  @JsonKey(defaultValue: [])
  List<String> tag;

  /// Returns a JSON representation of the 'CardInfo' instance.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CardInfoToJson(this);
}
```

Now you can use them.

Answer (score -1):

this pkg can help you convert JSON to a class instance. https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-converter

```
import { property, toClass } from 'class-convert';

class UserModel {
  @property('i')
  id: number;

  @property()
  name: string;
}

const userRaw = {
  i: 1234,
  name: 'name',
};

// use toClass to convert plain object to class
const userModel = toClass(userRaw, UserModel);
// you will get a class, just like below one
{
  id: 1234,
  name: 'name',
}
```