# Get a json object in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Good afternoon, I seek one through an api, a json.

Change de code...

data.dart

```
static _allItens() async {
    Network network = Network();
    final List list = await network.getData();
    final String _item = JSON.jsonEncode(list);
    final String jsonString = _item;
    print("jsonString")
    return jsonString;
}
```

In console, the json is returned ok.  In same class I need to get values in return to _allItens.

I called _allItens in:

```
Widget _buildTab(BuildContext context, HomeTab tab, List<String>SObj) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      key: ValueKey<HomeTab>(tab),
      animation: Listenable.merge(<Listenable>[_searchQuery, widget.home]),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        **_allItens();
        // I need get values of _allItens**
        return _buildList(context, _filterBySearchQuery(_getList(widget.home, SObj)).toList(), tab);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping JSON into Class Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189282/mapping-json-into-class-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on @dangngocduc 's answer:

The thing you are looking for is JSON Serialisation and Deserialisation. The link is already shared in that answer, but I am sharing here again for completeness.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

So, your final code should look like:

```
void _getList() async {
  Network network = Network();
  final List list = await network.getData();
  final String jsonString = JSON.jsonEncode(list);
  var serialisedObject = jsonDecode(jsonString);
  print(list);
}
```

Also, note that I have removed new keyword from your code, which is not necessary.
If this solves your problem, do not forget to upvote and check it as an answer.

Thanks

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Comment: that means you have List instead of map the object... Use var instead of strict type to avoid these exceptions... Edited answer...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read this document:

[JSON and serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)

You should convert json data to your model and use this model to working in class home.dart

Comment: but, how to call _getList() in another component?

Comment: you can create a ApiService has function _getList()  and inject this apiService to component with injection (provider, get_it). 

https://pub.dev/packages/provider

https://pub.dev/packages/get_it

Comment: you can read this post, it using InheritedWidget to inject api to widget.
https://www.filledstacks.com/post/flutter-dependency-injection-a-beginners-guide/